# pip install doesn't work correctly in docker

Tags: linux, networking, docker, ubuntu-16.04

### Question

i can't install any package during building an image. pulling from docker hub is OK, but problems occurred when docker try to use network to build an image. for example, if i try to run:

```
$ docker build -t sample-image:latest .
```

... and the Dockerfile that used by above command has following line:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

... then i get next error:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fdbe102e278>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/sanic/

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sanic (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sanic (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

... the same error appear when ubuntu packages are updating

---

### Info

docker and docker compose installed by official docker's documentation (without any changes).

```
Server Version: 17.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
Kernel Version: 4.8.0-45-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.763 GiB
```

requirements.txt:

```
sanic
asyncpg
asyncio
uvloop
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5-onbuild

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it
CMD ["./run/wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "index.py"]
```

---

### P.S.

i test more decisions and none helped yet. thanks for help everyone :)

Comment: Could this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668180/cant-install-pip-packages-inside-a-docker-container-with-ubuntu/35277904 be helpful?

Comment: How are you defining the sanic dependency in your `requirements.txt`? The `/simple/sanic/` looks odd

Comment: [shizhz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1000254/shizhz), unfortunately decision above doesn't helped me (behavior of image building doesn't change)... can you any other ideas?

Comment: [Matt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1318694/matt), requirements.txt so clear (look above). All this code works pretty cool at another computer with other hardware but the same software. It confuse me :(

Comment: @YuriiRabeshko Try to edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and comment out the `dns=dnsmasq` part, restart the network and docker and try again

Comment: [Salem](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1205368/salem), you are crazy man ;) i was finding a solution for 2 weeks but decision of the problem was so easy to fix.. thank you veeeeeery much))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks [Salem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1205368/salem)! following decision helped me:

> Try to edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and comment out
>   the dns=dnsmasq part, restart the network and docker and try again

Comment: Running docker 1.11.2 on ubuntu-xenial in a VirtualBox VM. The other dns suggestions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668180/cant-install-pip-packages-inside-a-docker-container-with-ubuntu/35277904 didn't help but this did.

Answer (score 0):

If pip install succeeds when installing packages on host machine but not during docker build, then the solution that worked for me is to have the `index-url` from the host machine's `/etc/pip.conf` present in that of the docker image.

**Example:**

If the host machine's `/etc/pip.conf` contains:

- `index-url = https://example.com/blah/blah/blah`

Then add the following line to the `Dockerfile` before installing any pip packages:

- `RUN echo '[global]\nindex-url = https://example.com/blah/blah/blah\ntrusted-host = https://example.com' > /etc/pip.conf`