# Can't download python packages onto Docker image

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have been following the official Docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#define-a-container-with-a-dockerfile).

My `Dockerfile`, `app.py` and `requirements.txt` are same as that given in the tutorial.
When I try to build my Docker image using `docker build -t friendlyhello .` I get the following error while docker runs the `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` section:

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/flask/

I have already checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668180/cant-install-pip-packages-inside-a-docker-container-with-ubuntu) and tried all the proposed solutions none seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: My requirements.txt

`Flask
 Redis`

The complete output

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.608 kB
Step 1/7 : FROM python:2.7-slim
---> 4ba53c70eb04
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
---> Using cache
---> bebf675fc3bd
Step 3/7 : ADD . /app
---> Using cache
---> 435299812b68
Step 4/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
---> Running in 97465239272f
Collecting Flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after       connection broken by'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f29c8b33910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f29c8bb9f90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f29c9aa69d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f29c9aa6190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f29c9aa6510>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/flask/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Edit 2: I found out my company uses a specific DNS using which I could resolve `docker run --dns [DNS] busybox nslookup google.com`

Comment: Please add your `requirements.txt`and the full output.

Comment: I have tried the same stuff in my server and it is working. Trying to understand your setup, can you ping to google.com from your containers ?  run this command "docker run busybox nslookup google.com"

Comment: @Here_2_learn Seems like it didn't work as expected. I ended up getting the message `nslookup: can't resolve 'google.com'`.

Comment: @Here_2_learn please see Edit 2.

Comment: make sure you have your company dns in `/etc/resolv.conf` or configure the docker daemon to point to that!

Comment: @QasimSarfraz Could you please let me know how to configure my daemon for that?

Comment: @VivekShankar : try with the answer provided now..it will help in resolving the issue.

Comment: @VivekShankar seems like people have already provided the details. Let me know if they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update your daemon to use a different DNS address, you can create (or modify) the /etc/docker/daemon.json file with the following:

```
{
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.2.2"]
}
```

Just replace the above IP's with your own requirements and when finished, you can run a reload or restart on your daemon to reread the file.

```
sudo systemctl reload docker
```

This should change the default DNS for all new containers including those used when building.

See the following link for more details on what you can set in this file: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#linux-configuration-file

Comment: I carried out your instructions but `nslookup` couldn't resolve google.com even after I updated the `daemon.json` file. However if I manually add the dns with `--dns <DNS>` it works.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in resolving the DNS in the containers. To resolve that follow the procedure which help to resolve the DNS in docker containers:

**Find out the DNS server used in your machine :**

```
# nm-tool  |grep DNS
    DNS:             172.24.100.50
    DNS:             10.1.100.50
```

**Run it again using DNS IP found in the above step which resolves the DNS issue:**

```
# docker run --dns 172.24.100.50 busybox nslookup google.com
Server:    172.24.100.50
Address 1: 172.24.100.50 indc01.radisys.com
Name:      google.com
Address 1: 2607:f8b0:4009:80c::200e ord36s01-in-x0e.1e100.net
Address 2: 172.217.4.110 ord36s04-in-f14.1e100.net
```

**To resolve it permanently add the following content as below to a new file:**

```
# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "dns" : ["172.24.100.50", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

More info on Docker DNS configuration : https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/

**Restart the docker service and check it again:**

```
# docker run busybox nslookup google.com
Server:    172.24.100.50
Address 1: 172.24.100.50 indc01.radisys.com
Name:      google.com
Address 1: 2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e ord30s31-in-x0e.1e100.net
Address 2: 172.217.4.238 ord30s31-in-f14.1e100.net
```

**Check it by running the container:**

```
root@labadmin-VirtualBox:/home/labadmin# docker run -it e02e811dd08f
/ # ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.4.238): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.4.238: seq=0 ttl=47 time=251.506 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.4.238: seq=1 ttl=47 time=245.621 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 245.621/257.113/272.586 ms
/ #
```

Comment: I carried out your instructions but `nslookup` couldn't resolve google.com even after I updated the `daemon.json` file.

Comment: However if I manually add the dns with `--dns <DNS>` it works just fine. Any work around this because I can't append `--dns <DNS>` to the `docker build` command.

Comment: Did you restart the docker service??

Comment: yes I did..but it proved futile. Could you explain the accepted answer(my answer) instead?