# Docker curriculum tutorial, python pip fails

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am following the tutorial in https://docker-curriculum.com/ to produce my first Docker image. In section 2.4 we are taught how to configure a simple Dockerfile using the base image `python:3-onbuild` that will automatically run pip and install dependencies from the `requirements.txt`.

The problem is the when I try to build docker, the packages simply fail to load:

```
mgitt@mgpc:~/workspace/docker-curriculum/flask-app$ docker build -t prakhar1989/catnip .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  8.704kB
Step 1/3 : FROM python:3-onbuild
# Executing 3 build triggers...
Step 1/1 : COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
 ---> Using cache
Step 1/1 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 74c4e94fa1ba
Collecting Flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc6592831d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc659283cc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc659283208>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc659283470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc659283ba8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
mgitt@mgpc:~/workspace/docker-curriculum/flask-app$
```

I have taken a look at this [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668180/cant-install-pip-packages-inside-a-docker-container-with-ubuntu/). These answers seem to have fixed many peoples problem issue of not being able to connect with the Domain Name Server (DNS) but resetting docker or adding the DNS to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` did nothing for me.

I have Docker version `17.09.0-ce` installed and am running on Ubuntu `16.04`, any ideas?

Comment: @JanezKuhar This doesn't seem to be the issue, as I am pulling a `User image`, it is like cloning someones repository. I also tried your solution, this led to the same result

Comment: The error message says there's a connection error when trying to reach to https://pypi.python.org/pypi.  Can the machine you're building the image on connect to that site?

Comment: No I cannot. Essentially the problem is that I cannot connect to the server because my machine can't find the correct DNS. But after trying the solutions in the SO solution, I am still unable to connect

Comment: Are you running behind a proxy?

Comment: In firefox I managed to find `Use system proxy settings` enabled. I supposed this means my entire system uses a proxy

Comment: This has been the most helpful link yet https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/

Comment: I tried the above on a different computer, on a different network. Ubuntu 16.04 and it had no problems downloading Flask, so @yamenk you are on to something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working on a proxy. There is a strong probability that docker containers cannot reach the internet at all.

You can test this by running

```
$ docker run -it busybox sh
/ # ping google.com
```

If it hangs you know you have a problem. Now we must find the network interface that your host machine uses to connect to the internet. `ipconfig` will give you a list of names, whichever one is used to connect to the internet is your IFACENAME. Now run:

```
$ nmcli dev list | grep 'IP4.DNS'                    # Ubuntu <= 14
$ nmcli device show IFACENAME | grep IP4.DNS         # Ubuntu >= 15
```

This will list out the IP_ADDRESS that your proxy server is located on. There may be more than 1, just use the first one. Create the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with the following contents:

```
{
    "dns": ["IP_ADDRESS", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

Lastly,

```
$ sudo service docker restart
```

You should now be able to ping from within a container.