# pip not working for requirements.txt when running autobahn Python with make start

Tags: python-3.x, pip, wamp, crossbar

I've set up a project following https://crossbar.io/docs/Getting-Started/ and running a Python client works fine.

Now, I want to use `pandas` in my Python client, so:

1. I've added `import pandas as pd` to client_aoi.py
2. I added `pandas` to `requirements.txt`
3. I uncommented `pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt` in run

However, when running `make start` to run the Python client, I get stuck with:

```
make start
docker run -v /home/*file_path*/app:/app  -it --rm --link crossbar crossbario/autobahn-python
Collecting pandas (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f488ba7d780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again',)': /simple/pandas/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f488ba7d978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again',)': /simple/pandas/
```

It seems the problem is with Docker, but the following options didn't work for me:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/790778
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41989423/3399066
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47319980/3399066

Since the Python client can only run when crossbar.io is running, I thought crossbar might be related to the DNS settings? Also, I'm behind an university network, so this might be related? Although normal pip works for me.

## Question

Any idea how I can have pip install the library I want (e.g. `pandas`) when I run the command `make start` for my Python client?

Comment: could you try: `docker run -it --rm python /usr/local/bin/pip install pandas` (works for me: https://gist.github.com/oberstet/05933457bf54909e447966e5b415b11c). it might be related to web proxies and/or missing certs for TLS cert chains ...in your specific univ. network

Comment: Thanks for trying. Unfortunately that doesn't work either. Probably something on my University network and Docker is fighting.

Comment: as long as you cannot make above simple example work, this is highly likely related to your general network environment  - not autobahn. don't waste time looking there .. check with your sysadmins ..