# pip3 install without sudo in a venv virtual environment fails with "Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I am trying to install flask with pip3 in a virtual environment and it fails when I run

```
(VirtEnv) $ pip3 install flask
```

With:

```
Collecting flask
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f870ae3bc18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/flask/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for flask
```

However when I run with sudo, the command succeeds but I've read this will install the file outside the virtual environment when using sudo. Running outside the virtual environment also succeeds.

Comment: Hint, shouldn't it be: "*Name or service not known*"?

Comment: @CristiFati yes, I was shortening to fit in the title. Should that tell me the solution?

Comment: Yes it should: make sure you can access *flask* site.

Comment: Try `pip3 install Flask==1.0.1`

Comment: @christifati that fixed it

Comment: @PuffinGDI The DNS was resolved wrongly within a virtual environment using a local dns server.

Answer (score 0):

Previously for another project, I had set up a local DNS and had changed my dns settings to use a local DNS server 192.168. and my local gateway as the dns. I could access flask from my computer but something about the virtual environment didn't work until I set the DNS servers to google 8.8.8.8. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668180/cant-install-pip-packages-inside-a-docker-container-with-ubuntu) for instructions.