# Cannot install requirements.txt in Dockerfile with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pip, proxy, dockerfile

I cannot install the pip requirements in the Dockerfile.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.7.1
ADD requirements.txt .

# increase pip timeout time
ENV PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT 60

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} -r requirements.txt
```

and the requirements.txt

```
apache-airflow==2.7.1
pandas==2.0.3
fastparquet
pytest
```

when I try to run the `docker compose up --build` command it gets stuck here:

```
 > [airflow-local-env-airflow-triggerer 4/4] RUN pip install apache-airflow==2.7.1 -r requirements.txt:
 => => # Requirement already satisfied: apache-airflow==2.7.1 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.7.1)                                                                      
 => => # Requirement already satisfied: pandas==2.0.3 in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.0.3)                                          
 => => # WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnectio
 => => # n object at 0x7f4941a58340>, 'Connection to 10.12.9.140 timed out. (connect timeout=60.0)')': /simple/fastparquet/                                                                    
 => => # WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnectio
 => => # n object at 0x7f4941a58820>, 'Connection to 10.12.9.140 timed out. (connect timeout=60.0)')': /simple/fastparquet/
```

airflow and pandas are requirements already satisfied by the base image so they are skipped and other **requirements cannot be installed**.

I tried entering the running container with `docker exec -it docker exec -it airflow-local-env-airflow-worker-1 sh` and running `pip install pytest` and **everything works fine** but for some reason it won't work if I try to install the requirements in the Dockerfile.

I am behind my company's proxy but I don't think that's the problem since in my `.docker/config.json` I have configured the proxy.

```
{
    "auths": {
        "artifactory.ocp-sdp.p4avd.mycompany.com": {
            "auth": "mytoken"
        }
    },
    "credsStore": "desktop",
    "proxies": {
        "default": {
            "httpProxy": "http://myuser:mypwd@the_ip:8080",
            "httpsProxy": "http://myuser:mypwd@the_ip:8080",
            "noProxy": "localhost,127.0.0.1,172.17.0.,.mycompanyname.com,cc-artifactory.mycompanyname.net,artifactory.ocp-sdp.p4avd.mycompanyname.com"
        }
    },
    "currentContext": "desktop-linux"
}
```

I tried the following things suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668180/cant-install-pip-packages-inside-a-docker-container-with-ubuntu) other SO question:

- Add  `--proxy=http://user:pass@addr:port` to the pip command
- Add network=host to the `docker-compose.yaml` (operation not permitted)
- Restarting everithing

EDIT 1:
I modified the sistemd files as suggested in @Paolo 's comment

```
cat .config/systemd/user/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf 
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pwd@ip:8080"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:pwd@ip:8080"
Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,172.17.0.,.company.com,cc-artifactory.company.net,artifactory.ocp-sdp.p4avd.company.com"
```

but I still get the same errors (`Could not connect to 10.12.9.140:8080 (10.12.9.140), connection timed out`)

Comment: The problem is not related to only pip and python, I just tried installing vim in the image and I get the same errors

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy), you should modify the systemd service file

Comment: @Paolo I modified the systemd and with `docker info` I get  
HTTP Proxy: http://xxxxx:xxxxx@ip:8080
HTTPS Proxy: http://xxxxx:xxxxx@ip:8080, also with `sudo systemctl show --property=Environment docker` but I still cannot install things

Comment: You don't necessarily have to install airflow in an `apache/airflow:2.7.1` container. If you must install, you can try using  `ubuntu` as your base image then run your installations. That may be the reasons while most of your commands are failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the network is not set to [host](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/). To make it work use the network option like this: `docker build --network=host` or, if you're using `docker compose` like I was, use the following syntax:

```
...
build:
    context: .
    network: host
...
```

and then build with `docker compose up --build`