# Error connecting PyPI in Docker container on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I ran into a problem when trying to build a Docker container for my Ubuntu 20.04 based project. The project includes work with Python and Docker. I use Docker-compose to manage my containers. In one of the containers that should run a Python script, an error occurs when trying to install dependencies from the requirements.txt file via pip.

```
Step 6/7 : RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in c0541b922fbc
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/aiofiles/
```

My .yml:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: None
      POSTGRES_USER: None
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: None
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: None
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: None
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  
  telegram-bot:
    container_name: telegram-bot
    build:
      context: ./bot_elephant
    volumes:
      - ./bot_elephant
    env_file:
      - ./bot_elephant/.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres


volumes:
  pg_data:
```

Dockerfile in bot_elephant:

```bash
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . .

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD python main.py
```

Comment: Step 6/8 : RUN wget pypi.org
 ---> Running in 7d99a7a70603
--2024-01-25 18:11:20--  http://pypi.org/
Resolving pypi.org (pypi.org)... 151.101.0.223, 151.101.192.223, 151.101.128.223, ...
Connecting to pypi.org (pypi.org)|151.101.0.223|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://pypi.org/ [following]
--2024-01-25 18:11:20--  https://pypi.org/
Connecting to pypi.org (pypi.org)|151.101.0.223|:443... connected.

Comment: I have tried your Dockerfile and it works as charm for me. Did you check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31806938/11502612? Furthermore, you can try to add `--network=host` to your docker command (Or add `network: host` section for the Python service in your compose file). If that ideas are not working, then please add `-vvv` for `pip3` command to see where is the problem in the connection.

Comment: The problem was in UMT, the threshold on the server was 1450, when the standard was 1500. Therefore, it was necessary to set 1450 in the settings in Docker